# BS4: How would I remove unncessary html tags and only keep the <p> and <ruby> tags?

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I can most likely accomplish this by using regex, but I feel like there must be an easier way to accomplish this. I have a tendency to make everything harder than it should be sadly.

```
<p><span class="colorL"><ruby>三重県<rt>みえけん</rt></ruby></span>の<span class="colorL"><ruby>伊賀市<rt>いがし</rt></ruby></span>は、<a class="dicWin" href="javascript:void(0)" id="id-0000"><ruby><span class="under">忍者</span><rt>にんじゃ</rt></ruby></a>の<a class="dicWin" href="javascript:void(0)" id="id-0001"><span class="under">ふるさと</span></a>だと<ruby>言<rt>い</rt></ruby>われています。</p>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use CSS selectors built within BeautifulSoup:

```
data = '''<p><span class="colorL"><ruby>三重県<rt>みえけん</rt></ruby></span>の<span class="colorL"><ruby>伊賀市<rt>いがし</rt></ruby></span>は、<a class="dicWin" href="javascript:void(0)" id="id-0000"><ruby><span class="under">忍者</span><rt>にんじゃ</rt></ruby></a>の<a class="dicWin" href="javascript:void(0)" id="id-0001"><span class="under">ふるさと</span></a>だと<ruby>言<rt>い</rt></ruby>われています。</p>'''

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'lxml')
print(soup.select('ruby, p'))
```

This will selects only `<ruby>` and `<p>` tags:

```
[<ruby>言<rt>い</rt></ruby>, <ruby>三重県<rt>みえけん</rt></ruby>, <ruby>伊賀市<rt>いがし</rt></ruby>, <ruby><span class="under">忍者</span><rt>にんじゃ</rt></ruby>, <p><span class="colorL"><ruby>三重県<rt>みえけん</rt></ruby></span>の<span class="colorL"><ruby>伊賀市<rt>いがし</rt></ruby></span>は、<a class="dicWin" href="javascript:void(0)" id="id-0000"><ruby><span class="under">忍者</span><rt>にんじゃ</rt></ruby></a>の<a class="dicWin" href="javascript:void(0)" id="id-0001"><span class="under">ふるさと</span></a>だと<ruby>言<rt>い</rt></ruby>われています。</p>]
```

Answer (score 2):

Like this:

```
data = BeautifulSoup(your_html, 'html.parser')
clean_data = (data.find_all('p'),data.find_all('ruby'))
print(clean_data)
```

To get the content/text within those tags:

```
p_text = clean_data.find_all('p').get_text()
```

Let me know if this works.

Comment: You can simply use `find_all(['p', 'ruby'])`.

Comment: OK, just that I'm still relatively new to web scraping.